# How to uninstall a gem from Rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubymine

I'm a n00b in Rails and Rubymine IDE. The Rubymine Help says to

> To uninstall gems, use command line procedure. So doing, the
>   recommended command format depends on the Ruby gems version you use.

`gem uninstall <gem_name>`

Could not how to figure out where to run the command and the Help does show this either. Let me know if there are any add'l steps that need to be done, such as `unbundling` the gem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run in the terminal/console a command:

```
gem install <gem_name>
```

In case if you using several RVM sets, then go to `File/Setting/Ruby SDK and Gems` and check which gem set used by RubyMine. Then check the gemset in terminal by command:

```
rvm gemset list
```

You will see the current gem set, you can change it if you need by command:

```
rvm gemset use <gemset_name>
```

And then do the uninstalling.

Comment: I was going to try that but wasn't sure if the help docs were referring to some integrated command line. Thanks!